# Storing Floats as Ints, a Premature Optimization?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a table with `real` columns that contains daily statistics based on values in other tables of our application:

```
CREATE TABLE stat_summaries (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    date date NOT NULL,
    a_avg real NOT NULL,
    a_stddev real NOT NULL,
    a_z_score real NOT NULL,
    b_avg real NOT NULL,
    b_stddev real NOT NULL,
    b_z_score real NOT NULL,
    -- Plus six more letters
);
```

For all cases, I'm dealing with digits of the form `X.XX` or `XX.XX`. Error of ±0.1 is acceptable for all computations.

Given that, a part of me thinks its a good idea to store these 18 fields as `smallint`s and remember to perform all further queries and calculations at that scale. Then I'd only have to worry about readjusting final values at the view layer, which I already have to do anyway (e.g. 0.333333 -> 0.33, 23.111111 -> 23%). Performance advantages here are obvious, but I'm not sure how significant they are in the grand scheme of things (we're talking about 10K-30K records per day): I'd be storing half the amount of data and any future computations and serializations in the app would involve integers instead of floating point numbers.

There's another part of me that thinks I'll pay for this decision somehow in the future, since it somewhat compromises the ergonomics of the code since I'll need to keep track of which columns map to which numeric format (`X.XX` or `XX.XX`) throughout development.

Comment: The perfomance advantages are *not obvious* (at least not to me), and I do believe you'll pay for this decision in the future (and maybe sooner than you think), mostly in the form of bugs.

Comment: One immediate pitfall I can see is if you want to aggregate up to monthly or yearly metrics. You could do that cheaply by building on your daily aggregates. But if you round aggressively, errors will add up.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `real` or `double` in the first place if you want to be able to retrieve the same value that you stored: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: I'm completely aware of the inconsistencies, but I really don't care about that level of precision. Error of  ±0.1 is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance of database dominated by I/O. Simple computation is minor factor. When modeling database, you should consider data integration rather than optimizing data type.

10~30K records per day, which means 3M ~ 10M records per year, is not huge amount in the database perspective.

Storing floating point numbers into integers is not a good idea. I'm not sure how much performance benefit you could get from distorting the data.

So, I think the most proper data type for your case is `Numeric(4,2)`.

And, perhaps you want to benchmark the two cases, check the differences of performance, maintainability, and development convenience. If you face the serious performance problem when you use `Numeric`, then you could consider `smallint` at the time.